# How can you get more detailed exception information from a vectored exception handler?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, exception

In a Windows application, if you have a vectored exception handler:

```
LONG WINAPI VectoredExceptionHandler(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS exception)
{

}
```

...and add it in like this...

```
AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, VectoredExceptionHandler);
```

If the handler is called, you get contextual information on your exception such as the exception code, `exception->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode` and exception information, `exception->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionInformation`. How do you translate this information into a string type (such as TCHAR) that tells the user what the exact problem that occurred was? For example, if you were to write a mini-dump using the WINAPI method, `MiniDumpWriteDump` to write a dump file, it will show you details like this in the dump file:

> Exception Code: 0xC0000005
>
> Exception Information: The thread tried to read from or write to a
>   virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.

I can convert the exception code quite easily, but how would you get such detailed exception information? `exception->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionInformation`, which in my environment is a `ULONG_PTR` (Windows 8.1 x64 running this application built in Release / x64 Platform / Multi-Byte Character Set) looks like this when I write it out to a `tstringstream`: `0000000000A2DF80`

Comment: You can probably get a textual description of the exception code by calling [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information is documented as part of [the documentation of the `EXCEPTION_RECORD` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **ExceptionInformation**
>
> An array of additional arguments that describe the exception. ...
>   The following table describes the exception codes whose array elements are defined.
>
> **EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION**
>
> The first element of the array contains a read-write flag that indicates the type of operation that caused the access violation. If
>   this value is zero, the thread attempted to read the inaccessible
>   data. If this value is 1, the thread attempted to write to an
>   inaccessible address. If this value is 8, the thread causes a
>   user-mode data execution prevention (DEP) violation.
>
> The second array element specifies the virtual address of the inaccessible data.

Comment: Is the documentation for ExceptionInformation[1] correct? I always get -1 for that value even when I know the virtual address being accessed isn't -1.